# How to download Appium Desktop in Ubuntu 16

Tags: automation, appium, appium-ios, appium-android

I am trying to download Appium Desktop in Ubuntu 16 (I've just been using the terminal to run it so far).

I understand that for Ubuntu, I must download the source code release they have on git (Source Code tar.gz), as apposed to their .exe (windows) or .dmg (mac) releases. After downloading it and un-tarring it, I do not know how to "install" it. I tried reading the README.md, but cannot find the instruction.
How to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can read the readme.md file inside it and check how to start appium desktop version

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Unable to find the instruction that explains it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1.2.0-beta.2 offers an AppImage for Linux - https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/

Download it, run chmod a+x on it, and then ./AppImage to execute it.

Comment: Working example for AppiumDesktop 1.17.1-1 and Ubuntu using command line `wget https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/download/v1.17.1-1/Appium-linux-1.17.1-1.AppImage` then `chmod u+x *.AppImage` and finally `./Appium-linux-1.17.1-1.AppImage`

Answer (score 2):

Offical url: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases

If you have no idea which file to download, there's a file contains "**linux**" and end with format "**yml**", the file name is contained in it.

The file should be an AppImage file as above mentioned, you should change the permission by checking box of **"Allow executing file as program"** of its "**Properties**".

And then run "**./appiumimagename**" in terminal to launch Appium Desktop or install it.

Answer (score 2):

download file named'Appium-linux-1.18.2.AppImage'.
change file permission to "Allow executing file as program" in file properties.
Right click and click on RUN.