# automate android app without id [appium]

Tags: android, android-studio, automation, appium

Our dev team released app. I am inspecting it with monitor (android studio tool) and try to find id but there is no id or anything how can i automate this app?

Please find below, attached sample screen shots:

[image]

[image]

without id i have no idea how to automate? if there are any ways to automate this app let me know.

Comment: Hi, please use appium inspector. It will help you to locate the elements. Please visit here for more info : https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop

Comment: thz ill check but im using ubuntu

Comment: could you check out this please :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142739/how-to-download-appium-desktop-in-ubuntu-16

Comment: i checked @SurajJogdand but :(

Comment: @SurajJogdand i run appium desktop its show empty page only i can inspect home page (full page only) when i try some new app its work fine thz i lean new thinks :)

Comment: @suraj  appium desktop now working post this as answer ill make as accept

Comment: Please use **appium inspector** for desktop. It will help you to locate the elements. Please visit [here](http://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) for more info. You may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142739/how-to-download-appium-desktop-in-ubuntu-16) out for more info on how to install appium inspector in ubuntu. Thanks!!

Comment: done. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath locator for the e-mail element (untested):

```
//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(), 'Email')]/preceding-sibling::android.widget.EditText
```

This locates the textview following the editview based on the text value, then points to the preceding sibling.

Same idea with the button, but just use the textview itself:

```
//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(), 'Log in')]
```

Also untested, but I believe both should work.

Comment: thz ill test  but other problem is in password option no test no id what should i do? thz for replay